# ipython uses my config file, but through django_extensions & shell_plus, it doesn't

Tags: django, ipython, django-extensions

My ipython config file is not being loaded by django_extensions' shell_plus.

My ipython config file contains:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = ['aa=5',]
```

testing it:

```
(virtualenv) $ ipython
>>>  ....
In [1]: aa
Out[1]: 5
```

works.  Now, testing the ipython called through django_extensions:

```
(virtualenv) $ python manage.py shell_plus
```

this gets me into ipython (highlighting works, %run works etc.), but without my config loaded:

```
In [1]:aa
NameError: name 'aa' is not defined
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because shell_plus.py uses `IPython.embed` not `IPython.start_ipython` to start the shell.  Embed doesn't load your configuration file.  Change the code or use things like SHELL_PLUS_PRE_IMPORTS to load what you want.